How to fix create_dtm() errors in an environment with text2vec 0.6.4 when using a model trained in version 0.5.1?
We have an LDA model trained with text2vec 0.5.1 and R 3.6.3. Every day this model is retrieved and used to inference daily incoming new article data.
Due to an impending system upgrade to text2vec 0.6.4 and R 4.4.2, we are testing whether our daily inference job can run in the new environment, still using the same trained model. The inference job works fine in text2vec 0.5.1, but in text2vec 0.6.4 it fails at function create_dtm() with the error message:
Error in corpus_insert(vocab_corpus_ptr, iterator, grow_dtm, skip_grams_window_context,  : argument "binary_cooccurence" is missing, with no default
In the following code, we tried modifying the vectorizer function from the trained model to explicitly set argument binary_cooccurence = FALSE, but this results in another error:
Error in cpp_vocabulary_corpus_create(vocabulary$term, attr(vocabulary,  : could not find function "cpp_vocabulary_corpus_create"
Is there any way the R code can call the function cpp_vocabulary_corpus_create in package text2vec?
Because we have many applications built on the model trained from text2vec 0.5.1, we wish to retain it, instead of re-building a new model.
Suggestions to fix the cpp_vocabulary_corpus_create error are appreciated.
library(text2vec)
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)
library(yaml)
library(googleCloudStorageR)
library(arrow)

config <- read_yaml("config.yml")
bq_auth(path = config$bq_token)
gcs_auth(config$bq_token)

con <- dbConnect(bigrquery::bigquery(), project = "cw-test", page_size = 1000, quiet = FALSE)

### load tables which contains daily incoming new article data
i_article_kw_profile_bdf <- tbl(con, "p_t1.i_article_kw_profile")
i_article_kw_by_editor_bdf <- tbl(con, "p_t1.i_article_kw_by_editor")

### retrieve model trained with text2vec 0.5.1 from gcs
bu_name = "cw-opinion"
model_id = "article-n32"
model_ver = "20210827"
remote_path = paste0("gs://t1/lda-model-files/",bu_name,"/",model_id,"/",model_ver,"/model.rds")

# download trained model from gcs
cont <- gcs_get_object(remote_path, parseFunction = function(x){httr::content(x, as = "raw")})
raw_con <- gzcon(rawConnection(cont))
lda_model_from_rds <- readRDS(raw_con)
close(raw_con)

lda_model <- lda_model_from_rds$lda_model
vectorizer <- lda_model_from_rds$vectorizer # This is modified below
model2plot_df <- lda_model_from_rds$model2plot_df

# modify vectorizer to set binary_cooccurence = FALSE to avoid error
vectorizer <- function (iterator, grow_dtm, skip_grams_window_context, window_size, 
          weights, binary_cooccurence = FALSE) 
{
  vocab_corpus_ptr = cpp_vocabulary_corpus_create(vocabulary$term, 
                                                  attr(vocabulary, "ngram")[[1]], attr(vocabulary, "ngram")[[2]], 
                                                  attr(vocabulary, "stopwords"), attr(vocabulary, "sep_ngram"))
  setattr(vocab_corpus_ptr, "ids", character(0))
  setattr(vocab_corpus_ptr, "class", "VocabCorpus")
  corpus_insert(vocab_corpus_ptr, iterator, grow_dtm, skip_grams_window_context, 
                window_size, weights, binary_cooccurence)
}

## inference on new data
i_article_kw_profile_bdf2 <- 
  i_article_kw_profile_bdf %>% 
  filter(website == "cw_opinion") %>% 
  semi_join(i_article_kw_by_editor_bdf, by = "kw") %>% 
  select(article_id, kw, weight)

tokens_df <- 
  i_article_kw_profile_bdf2 %>% 
  collect() %>% 
  group_by(article_id) %>% summarise(tokens = list(kw))

tokens <- tokens_df$tokens
it = itoken(tokens, ids = tokens_df$article_id, progressbar = F)
new_dtm =  create_dtm(it, vectorizer, type = "dgTMatrix") # The code fails here 


Note that cpp_vocabulary_corpus_create() is not an exported function. Try text2vec:::cpp_vocabulary_corpus_create() instead. Also text2vec:::corpus_insert()
